# foreach in path construction behaves differently whether start is node or coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

In `tikZ`'s manual, following code is proposed to illustrate usage of `foreach` inside a path construction command:

[image]

On the image below, this is figure (1). Strangely, when the starting point (`(0,0)` in the above example) is replaced by a named node (figure (2)), the result  is completely different : the paths constructed in the loop no longer follow each other, they all start from the given node. Starting from named coordinates (figure (3)) again results in the wanted bahaviour.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
(1) \tikz \draw (0,0) foreach \x in {1,...,3} { -- (\x,1) -- (\x,0) };
(2) \tikz {\node (a) at (0,0) {}; \draw (a) foreach \x in {1,...,3} { -- (\x,1) -- (\x,0) };}
(3) \tikz {\coordinate (a) at (0,0); \draw (a) foreach \x in {1,...,3} { -- (\x,1) -- (\x,0) };}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't find anything about that in the manual. Maybe this cryptic line?

> Note that the node and pic path commands also support the foreach
> statement in special ways.

Now what should I do to be able to use such a construct but starting from a node?

Note : `pgffor.sty 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)`

Comment: use a dedicted coordinate from the node, e.g. \draw (a.center)

Comment: I can see the difference that makes when using `(a.center)` instead of just `a` but I still wonder why the foreach loop doesn't provide the same saw line. If someone could explain...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could do that, but if the starting node has content, the result would be different. I would actually have to find the precise anchor that tikZ would use when drawing between nodes. In the situation above, this is easy (`a.east`) but in general, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Expansion of foreach loop inside \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649314/expansion-of-foreach-loop-inside-draw) also. Basically, there are two things:

1. the movements of an in-line `foreach` act totally in a local way, as they were issued each one in a `{[current point is local] ... }` group. That means that the "current position" is reset at every loop.
2. When drawing a line starting from a node, Ti*k*Z uses the *border anchor* if it's available, so the line will not start from the center. You can retrieve the position using `coordinate[pos=0]` when the path is built (see below), but I do not know how to integrate that into your `foreach` code without a lot of gimmicks...

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node [circle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {Node};
    \draw (a) coordinate(naked-a) -- ++(1,2)
        coordinate[pos=0](border-a)
        coordinate[pos=1](final);
    \node [fill=red, circle, inner sep=2pt] at (naked-a) {}; 
    \node [fill=blue, circle, inner sep=2pt] at (border-a) {}; 
    \node [fill=green, circle, inner sep=2pt] at (final) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the code above]