# Expansion of foreach loop inside \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I have a hard time understanding the response to [the GitHub issue pgf-tikz/pgf#356](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/356).

[image: original picture]

The original question asker has posted the following MWE.  I've wrapped it with `\begin{document}` for completeness.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (v1)  at (0,0);
  \coordinate (c21) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (c22) at (2,0);
  \coordinate (v2)  at (2,1);
  \coordinate (c31) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (c32) at (3,2);
  \coordinate (v3)  at (4,2);
  \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6pt,circle] (a) at (v1) {};
  \draw (a) \foreach \i in {2,3} {.. controls (c\i1) and (c\i2) .. (v\i)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The reply to the linked question suggests that the `\foreach` is expanded to

```
\draw (a) .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2) 
      (a) .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3);
```

However, if the node `(a)` in the line containing `\foreach` in his MWE is replaced by the coordinate `(v1)`, then the `\foreach` loop isn't expanded to

```
\draw (v1) .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2) 
      (v1) .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3);
```

**Why is it expanded like the following?**

```
\draw (v1) .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2) 
           .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3);
```

[image]

The reply doesn't explain that.

There's no mention of `\iftikz@shapeborder` in PGF & Ti*k*Z manual, whose [chapter 88](https://tikz.dev/pgffor) says

> Note that the `node` and `pic` path commands also support the `foreach` statement in special ways.

Unluckily, there's no explanation about the "special ways" in the manual.

Comment: Jus looking at the line, you can see that `(a)` is outside of the `foreach`, so it will never expand to something with a repeated `(a)`. Edit: Ok - I am somewhat wrong.

Comment: Duplicate of [tikz pgf - foreach in path construction behaves differently whether start is node or coordinate - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594663/foreach-in-path-construction-behaves-differently-whether-start-is-node-or-coordi) but... that one is unanswered...

Comment: @user202729 answered, although it's not strictly a duplicate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between coordinates and nodes is that a node (normally) has size. That is, at least one of a node's height, depth, and width is greater than zero. Ti*k*Z/pgf takes care of this size and will always draw from/to node border when a node without anchor is used as coordinate, no matter that border is drawn or not. See pgfmanual, sec. 17.11 "Connecting Nodes: Using Nodes as Coordinates" ([html](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.11)) for more info.

Then comes the scoping property of `(\)foreach`. To support on-path `foreach`, quite some info should be backed-up and restored when each `foreach` loop is leaved and entered. Ti*k*Z has already handled some of such info (see [`tikz.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex), definition of `\tikz@foreach`), but it's far from comprehensive. [Issue #356](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/356) is one case for curve-to path operation, and [issue #1047](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1047) is another case for `turn` option.

For OP's current question, one can think that the coordinate version has been handled (by backing-up and restoring `\tikz@last[xy]` and `\tikz@last[xy]saved`), and the node version has not yet.

Anyway, for OP's question (and for [issue #356](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/356), it seems the only missing piece of info is `\tikz@moveto@waiting`, which is either let to `\relax` or `\edef`ed to hold `\tikz@shapeborder@name` (a node name).

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\tikzset{
  expected/.style={blue!10, line width=5pt},
  simulated/.style={blue!50, line width=3pt, opacity=.5},
  actual/.style={line width=.6pt}
}

\newcommand\test[2][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (v1)  at (0,0);
    \coordinate (c21) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (c22) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (v2)  at (2,1);
    \coordinate (c31) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (c32) at (3,2);
    \coordinate (v3)  at (4,2);
    \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6pt,circle] (a) at (v1) {};
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3,0)}, nodes={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}, y=.5cm]
      \node[anchor=south west, align=center] at  (0,1.5) {start from (#2)#1};
      \draw[expected]  (0, 1) -- +(1,0) node[right] {expected};
      \draw[simulated] (0,.5) -- +(1,0) node[right] {simulated};
      \draw[actual]    (0, 0) -- +(1,0) node[right] {actual};
    \end{scope}
    
    % expected
    \draw[expected]
      (#2) .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2)
          .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3);
  
    % simulated foreach
    \draw[simulated]
      (#2) .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2)
      (#2) .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3);
    
    % actual
    \draw[actual]
      (#2) \foreach \i in {2,3} {.. controls (c\i1) and (c\i2) .. (v\i)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\test[\\before patch]{a}
\test[\\before patch]{v1}

\makeatletter
% backup globally
\xpatchcmd*\tikz@foreach
  {\xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}}
  {\xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
   \global\let\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting=\tikz@moveto@waiting
   }
  {}{\PatchFailed}

% restore locally
\xpatchcmd*\tikz@foreach
  {\tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved}
  {\tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved
   \let\tikz@moveto@waiting=\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting
   }
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\test[\\after patch]{a}
\test[\\after patch]{v1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sor9y i can't understand neither the code in the linked TEX file where the `foreach` command is defined, nor the code you've given in the example.  idk any IDE/debugger for LaTeX.  a debugger for a normal programming language allows setting breakpoints and view the changes of variables in each step.  i can't see how the value `\tikz@last[xy]` has changed in the source code.  having other more important things to do, i'll let go this problem and rmb the functional explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no similar debugger for (La)TeX.

Answer (score 3):

What I understand is that `\foreach` creates full-local subpaths --- so it is basically equivalent to

```latex
\draw (a) { [current point is local] .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2) }
          { [current point is local] .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3) };
```

About the border things: the idea is that if you use a node like `(a)` as a coordinate, Ti*k*Z will put the coordinate on the border of the shape --- in this case using `(v1)` is like using `(a.center)`.

Code to play with:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (v1)  at (0,0);
  \coordinate (c21) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (c22) at (2,0);
  \coordinate (v2)  at (2,1);
  \coordinate (c31) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (c32) at (3,2);
  \coordinate (v3)  at (4,2);
  \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6pt,circle] (a) at (v1) {};
  \draw (a) \foreach \i in {2,3} {.. controls (c\i1) and (c\i2) .. (v\i)};
  \draw[blue]  (a) .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2)
                   .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3);
  \draw[red, dashed]  (a) { [current point is local] .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2) }
                  { [current point is local] .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the snippet above]

Comment: sorry i still don't get your answer after checking the definition of `current point is local`.  i'm more interested about the expansion of `\draw (a.center) ...` than in `\draw (a) ...`, but most of your answer covers the later.  say I replace `(a)` in the last `\draw` command in your answer with `(a.center)`.
`\draw[red, dashed]  (a.center) { [current point is local] .. controls (c21) and (c22) .. (v2) }
                  { [current point is local] .. controls (c31) and (c32) .. (v3) };`
after parsing the first `}`, why the `current point` is not reset to `(a.center)`?

Comment: Ah, you are right. No idea... sounds like a bug or an "unexpected feature", really.